# How to add a random name so that files won't replace php

Tags: php, wordpress

```
if(isset($_FILES['attachment'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['attachment']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['attachment']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['attachment']['name'])));
      
      $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");
      
      if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }
      
      if($file_size > 2097152){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }
      
   }
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO ".$tablename." (post_id, name, email, price, author, post_title, purchase_type, closing_date, concessions_amount, insp_from, insp_to, seller_charge, emd, home_warranty, seller_occupancy, attachment ) VALUES ( %d, %s, %s, %d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %d, %s, %s, %d, %d, %s, %s, %s )", $id, $name, $email, $price, $author, $post_title, $purchase_type, $closing_date, $concessions_amount, $insp_from, $insp_to, $seller_charge, $emd, $home_warranty, $seller_occupancy, $file_name );
    
    
    
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        
          function tp_wordpress_uploads_directory_path() {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    return $upload_dir['basedir'] . "/offers/";
}
        $upload_check =  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,tp_wordpress_uploads_directory_path().$file_name);
         
      }
```

Right now system is replacing existing file, can anyone help to add a random number so that file's names won't match, may be by adding currrent time and date into?
I know how to rand(); works but not getting the way to implement it into my code.

Comment: Try: $file_name = uniqid() . '_' . $_FILES['attachment']['name'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a built-in function specifically for generating random filenames:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

If you really want to append a random number to the filename then you could use:

```
$file_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'].rand(1,10000);
```

However, there's no guarantee it won't generate the same number twice or more times, resulting in the file being overwritten again.

Comment: thanks allot, can you add current date and time into it, that's always unique.

Comment: @qazidev uniqid() is based on the unix timestamp, you can reference here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Yes you could replace the `rand` function with the `time` or `date` function.  If using `date` just be careful to select a format that will work in filenames.

Comment: Got it, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in then you can use user's id or post's id (in this case after inserting the post) and timestamp as a filename, assuming that user's id or post's id is unique.

```
// or use post's id
$filename = $_SESSION['user_id'].'-'.time();
```